# Detect Windows version and run command according to version

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've found a way to make it work with this script

```
FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=1-2 DELIMS=." %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET VERSION'
) DO FOR %%C IN (%%A%%B) DO IF %%C EQU 62 GOTO :windows8
```

but this only works for a single version, and i would like to be able to add conditions to other versions

i've tried adding `ELSE IF %%C EQU 100 GOTO :windows10` but it doesn't work

can someone help me?

Comment: I bet you didn't put parentheses around `goto :windows8` when appending the `else` portion…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this in order to check Windows version :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Check Windows Version
for /f "tokens=4-7 delims=[.] " %%i in ('ver') do (if %%i==Version (set v=%%j.%%k) else (set v=%%i.%%j))
if "%v%" == "10.0" set "myOS=Windows 10"
if "%v%" == "6.3" set "myOS=Windows 8.1"
if "%v%" == "6.2" set "myOS=Windows 8"
if "%v%" == "6.1" set "myOS=Windows 7"
if "%v%" == "6.0" set "myOS=Windows Vista"
if "%v%" == "5.2" set "myOS=Windows XP" & REM WinXP 64Bit Edition
if "%v%" == "5.1" set "myOS=Windows XP"
if "%v%" == "5.0" set "myOS=Windows 2000"
cls
echo Current OS version: %myOS%
pause >NUL
@exit /B
```

Comment: worked like a charm, tysm!!

Comment: **Note:** Technically, the `ver` command from a batch file run in `cmd.exe`, returns the version information for `cmd.exe`, not for the Operating System. Whilst it may not be as common as it used to be, it is possible to replace cmd.exe with other versions, or even programs.